# How to consume ASP.NET WebAPI service (built in .NET Framework) in an application developed in UWP (Windows Runtime)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, uwp

I have a Universal Windows Application which is developed in Windows Runtime.  I want the UWP application to consume a RESTful API service developed in ASP.NET WebAPI (built in .NET Framework).  Is this doable?  I assumed that I can still use HttpClient library to connect and consume the API endpoints.  Is this also possible?

I have also googled to search for some answers, but all I can find are results related with ASP.NET Core WebAPI consume by UWP applications.

Also, if anyone could point me to some existing links/resources, that will be a good head start to work on.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be the same client side as consuming any restful service, including core web api.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Nkosi

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can do it, if UWP build by .NET Framework then you can call Web Api Service URI on runtime using HttpClient. CMIIW